# Compute the shortest distances beetween multiple point

Tags: algorithm

So here is the problem I have : I need an algorithm to , given a set of `n` points of coordinates `(x;y)` what is the shortest path to link all the points together , with no limitations at all , meaning a single point can link to any number of other points.

The first idea to solve the problem was for each unlinked point , find the nearest point and link to it , then remove those two points from the unlinked list of points and start over until you have no more unliked points. You have created blocks of near points at this stage. Then you link those blocks finding the shortest distance beetween them.

The problems of this method are 1. it does not give the shortest path 2. It seems quite inefficient , So I ask you , what type of algorithm does this kind of calculation (I just need the total distance between points , I don't care about how they are actually linked) ?

Comment: Sounds like a variation of [TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: Not quite like it thought , because here I can go as often to a "city" as I want.

Comment: what are the constraints? Optimal configuration of weights in graph is NP-complete so maybe on N <= 20 it will be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you can use a spanning tree algorithm. In pseudo-code:

```
build_tree(unconnected_nodes):
  connected_nodes = set()
  // pick a random unconnected node
  connected_nodes.add(unconnected_nodes.pop())

  while not empty(unconnected_nodes):
     best_connected_node = None
     best_unconnected_node = None
     shortest_distance = +Infinity

     for node1 in connected_nodes:
       for node2 in unconnected_nodes:
         if distance(node1, node2) < shortest_distance:
           shortest_distance = distance(node1, node2)
           best_unconnected_node = node2
           best_connected_node = node1
     connect(best_connected_node, best_unconnected_node)
     unconnected_nodes.remove(best_unconnected_node)
     connected_nodes(best_unconnected_node)

  return connected_nodes
```

This is assuming that you have something that's essentially a fully-connected graph and by "coordinates" and "no restrictions" I think that's what you have. If not, you need to traverse the set of vertexes from connected to unconnected nodes.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can apply Prim`s shortest path algorithm or Kruskal shortest path algorithm. These algorithms usually provide shortest path between two different nodes in a network. For your problem you can represent each co-ordinate pair as a vertex and find shortest path between them by creating a minimum spanning tree of edges. I am writing the pseudo code below:

```
mst = queue of all the result edges(or co-ordinates)
p =  queue of all the connected edges
while p is not empty
  edge e = min of p
  if union-find(both vertices of edge e)
    continue
  else
    union-find.add(both vertices of edge e)
    mst.add(e)
```

At the end you will have "mst" representing shortest path between all the co-ordinates

Comment: `p` is for example a list of elements composed of three values :  vertexes `a`,`b` and distance `ab` thats it ?

Comment: partially true , actually p represents a connection(edge) between vertex a and vertex b, you can think of it like distance(ab) or weight(ab). It is simply a list of all such edges like  (a-b, b-c, a-c) etc